# Interpreting DataFrame.where() documentation

Tags: pandas, methods

From examples outside of the documentation, I thought I understood the examples of the .where() method.  Basically, it seems to be a another way to filter a dataframe.

However, when I checked the documentation itself for an example of how to use .where(), it was counterintuitive.

The documentation provides this [example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/whatsnew.html#method-chaininng-improvements):

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
                    'B': [4, 5, 6],
                    'C': [7, 8, 9]})

df.where(lambda x: x > 4, lambda x: x + 10)

[output]: 
    A   B  C
0  11  14  7
1  12   5  8
2  13   6  9
```

It seems to me that this code should filter for all values greater than four.  According to my logic,

```
df.where(lambda x: x > 4, lambda x: x + 10)
```

should add 10 to all values greater than 4, changing the output to

```
    A   B  C
0   1   4 17
1   2  15 18
2   3  16 19
```

Could someone please explain to me the error in my logic?

Answer (score 1):

I assumed "where" meant "where condition is true, replace with X", but it's actually "Where this condition is true, KEEP the value".  This is odd to me but I found a different [documentation page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas.DataFrame.where) that more clearly explained the .where() method.

As it turns out, the [.mask()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas.DataFrame.mask) method would return what I expected from .where().  Specifically:

```
df.mask(lambda x: x > 4, lambda x: x + 10)
```